# Angular Material2 not all styles are applied

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

My problem is that styles for components as `<mat-chip>` or `<button mat-raised-button>`(just I found) are not working they are by default gray. For example style is applied for `<mat-card>`

Color properties are set as follow:

```
<mat-chip color="primary">
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">
```

I add theme `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";` in **styles.css** as is described in [Angular Material Guides - Theming](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.12/guides/theming.md).

Do I missed something? 
Angular Version: *4*
Angular Material Version: *2.0.0-beta.12*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to just import the theme, you have to set it up.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINING THE BASE THEMING
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-green);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
$dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

With that, you can chose your colors in the `$primary`, `$accent` or `$warn`, and chose the them to use (light or dark) with the `angular-material-theme($theme)` (or `$dark-theme`, but you figured it out).

Comment: My bad. Thank you

Comment: Actually, you don't really have to. It's probably something wrong with the way it was imported.

Comment: Just importing it doesn't define it. But I get your point, maybe they were already defined with default colors. Anyways, if this solution works, good for him !